# pyral get function does not return any results

Tags: python, rally, pyral

I installed pyral and try to retrieve a ticket from Rally, but no results are being returned. This happens in both Windows and Linux, and in both Python 2 and 3.

```
>>> import pyral
>>> r = pyral.Rally(apikey=apikey, project=projname)
>>> r.get("UserStory", fetch=True, query='FormattedID = "{}"'.format(ID))
200 QueryResult TotalResultCount: 0  Results: []
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by downgrading pyral from 1.4.0 to 1.2.3. It can be downloaded at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyral/1.2.3. This fixed the issue on both Windows and Linux, and on Python 2 and Python 3.

```
>>> import pyral
>>> r = pyral.Rally(apikey=apikey, project=projname)
>>> r.get("UserStory", fetch=True, query='FormattedID = "{}"'.format(ID))
HierarchicalRequirement result set, totalResultSetSize: 1, startIndex: 1  pageSize: 200  current Index: 0
```